# Efficient and fast way to padarray matrix

Tags: matlab, performance, zero-pad

I tried to `padarray` more than 1000 images. However when I time my code, this specific line take the highest amount of time to complete

```
I=abs(padarray(I, [2, 2], 'replicate', 'both'));
```

Mainly because of the line 35 of the `padarray` algorithm (inside profiler): **images\private\padarray_algo**

`b = a(aIdx{:});`

Any way to improve the efficiency? Perhaps using another method? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [repmat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [matrix concatenation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html) to get the same result:

```
r=@repmat;
pad=@(I,d)[r(I(1),d)    r(I(1,:),d(1),1)   r(I(1,end),d)
       r(I(:,1),1,d(2)) I                  r(I(:,end),1,d(2))
       r(I(end,1),d)    r(I(end,:),d(1),1) r(I(end),d)];
```

Usage:

```
pad(I,[2 2])
```

If all images are of the same size you can create a matrix of linear indices of the image and apply `padarray` to it then use padded index array to pad images:

```
%create matrix of indices
Idx = reshape(1:numel(I),size(I));
%pad the index
Idx_padded = padarray(Idx, [2, 2], 'replicate', 'both'); 
%use the padded index to pad images
result = I(Idx_padded);
result2 = I2(Idx_padded);
```

Comment: First method more or less the less since multiple calling of function. However that second method is genius! It saved me days of computation. Thank you so much!